# SpinLock and readonly fields

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Just reading through the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx) about new `.NET 4.0` feature [SpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx) and can not understand idea behind the following statement:

> Do not store SpinLock instances in readonly fields.

My feelings that this is somehow related to value-type specifics but not sure how exactly and why. Could anybody bring more light on this point?

Comment: @Chriseyre2000 : why you've deleted your answer? it is fine but of very low quality I believe this is why someone downvoted it. Just bring more details and undelete I will +1 anyway since you was the first who answered. Thanks! I've really overlooked MSDN page comment yu've mentioned

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The underlying problem is that the C# compiler creates a copy of a `readonly` value type field when you call a non-static method on it and executes that method on the copy - because the method *could* have side effects that change the value of the struct - which is not allowed for `readonly` fields.

For further clarification see ["Mutating Readonly Structs"](http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/).

Comment: Gross. I find it hard to believe that they would so something so recklass as make a mutable object a struct, let alone one as important as a lock.

Comment: +1 and thanks, great stuff! Shame to me that I was not aware of mutable readonly structs before.

Comment: @JonathanAllen SpinLock is meant as a most lightweight lock object. It is for advanced use-cases.

Comment: @sll The entire purpose of the `SpinLock` is that an instance method call mutates the struct. Specifically, when you do `mySpinLock.Enter(ref wasLockSuccessful);` then the method call changes the state of `mySpinLock`. Now, if `mySpinLock` is a field declared with `readonly`, it is the state of a **copy** of the field which is changed. The bool `wasLockSuccessful` is set to true. But when you examine the original (as opposed to the copy which was not kept) `mySpinLock`, then `mySpinLock.IsHeld` is still `false`. Removing the `readonly` modifier solves that.

Comment: After four years I haven't changed my opinion. Making it a strut is only justified if you expect someone to create thousands of spin locks, And I just don't see that happening.

Comment: Just ran across this, and I wasn't quite sure how to search for the problem. `lockTaken` was returning `true`, but `spinLock.IsHeld` was returning `false`. The explanation makes sense, realizing that `SpinLock` is a *mutable* `struct`, but it wasn't expected behavior at first glance.